# Android Studio: El teclado modifica mi diseño

Tags: android-studio

Coloqué una caja de texto (EditText) y debajo de ella un HorizontalScrollMenuView con varias ImageButton. El problema es que al dar click en la caja de texto y abrirse el teclado para escribir las ImageButton se desplazan hacia arriba y se hacen más pequeñas. Y así permanecen incluso después de cerrar el teclado.  Acá les dejo el código. ¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo resolverlo? De antemano muchas gracias.

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TxtBuscar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:width="800px"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/buscar" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/BtnBuscar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TxtBuscar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/TxtBuscar"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        android:background="#000000FF"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px"
        android:minWidth="60px"
        android:minHeight="60px"/>

</LinearLayout>



<com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenulibrary.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
    android:layout_marginRight="50px"
    app:backgroundMenuColor="#000000FF"
    app:icon_height="240dp"
    app:icon_width="160dp"
    app:item_backgroundColor="#000000FF"
    />
```

Comment: el > HorizontalScrollMenuView deberia estar dentro del linear layout para que se mantenga siempre debajo de los otros objetos o por lo contrario a tu linear layout le puedes cambiar a un constraint layout y usar gideline para la distribucion de los obejetos en la interfaz, yo te recomendaria lo segundo ya que es mucho mas facil realizarolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que declarar el atributo android:windowSoftInputMode en la cabecera.

Hay diferentes opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes toda la información al final de esta [página](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso lo que me hacía falta